# Does CPU 2GHz Intel Core i7 in MacBookPro 8,2 (Early 2011) support SSE4.2 ? If not, is there a way to make it happen?

Tags: cpu, macbook-pro

First of all i have to say that i'm a simple user without any furhter knowledge. I have no clue about CPU's, SSE and programming or what so ever. I'm (or was) just a happy user with my smoothly running MacBook which i mainly use to process pictures. To do so i'm working with Capture One. Since updating it to the latest Version (Capture One 21 Mac 14.0.2) the software is immediately crashing everything (right after opening up). The Macbook hangs-up and turns off. It takes several trials and up to half an hour to restart it. While doing so the macbook is running hot and the fan drives crazy.
On my request to the Capture One Support the answer is "It looks like your CPU doesn't support SSE4.2, which is queried since Capture One 20.1" together with the recommendation to go back to an older Version.
While waiting for the answer from the Support, a friend advised me to try to disable OpenCL before running Capture One and it worked, unfortunately only for two days.
I tried to research about Intel Core i7 and SSE4.2 and it didn't take me to long to realize that I won't get it at all by myself.
So if somebody knows  about this issue or can tell me, if the 2GHz Intel Core i7 in MacBookPro 8,2 (Early 2011) really doesn't support SSE4.2 at all or if there is a way to somehow update it to support SSE4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the
[Apple MacBook Pro 15-Inch "Core i7" 2.2 Early 2011 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.2-15-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html),
your CPU is the
[Intel Core i7-2720QM](https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i7/Intel-Core%20i7%20Mobile%20I7-2720QM%20FF8062700835817.html).

The description of the CPU includes this:

```
Extensions and Technologies

MMX instructions
SSE / Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2 / Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3 / Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3 / Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4 / SSE4.1 + SSE4.2 / Streaming SIMD Extensions 4
```

Conclusion: Your CPU supports SSE4.2.

Comment: Oh, that great news. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the CPU in your device is either an i7-2675QM, or an i7-2635QM. If this is the case, then they **do** support SSE4.2

Sources include Wikichip.org and cpu-world.com

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I would like to thank you for your feedback on my question.